# Using Redux Toolkit, how do I access the store from a non-react file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, redux-toolkit

**What am I trying to do?**

Using Redux Toolkit, I'm trying to access the "store" for a value, specifically "username" which I've created a "slice" for, from a non-React file called `SomeFile.js`.

**What is the code that currently tries to do that?**

```
// userMetadataSlice.js

import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  username: "",
};

const userMetadataSlice = createSlice({
  name: "userMetadata",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    updateUsername: (state, action) => {
      const username = action.payload;
      state.username = username;
    },
  },
});

export const { updateUsername } = userMetadataSlice.actions;

export default userMetadataSlice.reducer;

export const selectUsername = (state) => {
  return state.userMetadata.username;
}
```

```
// SomeFile.js

import { selectUsername } from "../redux/userMetadataSlice";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

export const displayUsername = () => {
  const username = useSelector(selectUsername);
  console.log("Username:", username); // Error.
}
```

**What do I expect the result to be?**

To be able to pull the username from the "store".

**What is the actual result?**

When I try to access the value via "useSelector" from the non-react file an error occurs: `React Hook "useSelector" is called in function "selectUsername" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function`

**What I think the problem could be?**

`SomeFile.js` does not have anything React related within it because it just pulls data from the store and outputs the data.

A solution I've tried that worked was to do this:

```
// userMetadataSlice.js

import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  username: "",
};

const userMetadataSlice = createSlice({
  name: "userMetadata",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    updateUsername: (state, action) => {
      const username = action.payload;
      state.username = username;
    },
  },
});

export const { updateUsername } = userMetadataSlice.actions;

export default userMetadataSlice.reducer;

export const selectUsername = (state) => {
  return state.userMetadata.username;
}

// New code here!

export function SelectUsername() {
  const username = useSelector(selectUsername);
  return username;
}
```

```
// SomeFile.js

import { SelectUsername } from "../redux/userMetadataSlice";

export const displayUsername = () => {
  console.log("Username:", SelectUsername); // No errors, shows correct output.
}
```

The solutions I'm looking for is this:

1. Is my proposed solution the "proper" way to receive info from the "store" in non-React files?
2. Is there a custom hook solution for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is my proposed solution the "proper" way to receive info from the
> "store" in non-React files?

No, it's abusing the Rules of Hooks and React functions. You are directly invoking the `SelectUsername` React function.

> Is there a custom hook solution for this?

No, React hooks work only in React functions and custom React hooks.

You can access your state from your Redux `store` object.

[Store](https://redux.js.org/api/store)

From your created `store` object you'll have a [`getState`](https://redux.js.org/api/store#getstate) method to invoke.

> ### `getState()​`
>
> Returns the current state tree of your application. It is equal to the
> last value returned by the store's reducer.
>
> **Returns**​
>
> (any): The current state tree of your application.

You can export your created store object for import into non-React JS files and they can invoke the `getStore` method.

```
import store from '../path/to/store';

...

const state = store.getState();
```

The `useSelector` React hook from `react-redux` won't work outside a React component, but the `selectUsername` state selector function will.

```
// SomeFile.js
import store from '../path/to/store';
import { selectUsername } from "../redux/userMetadataSlice";

...

export const displayUsername = () => {
  const state = store.getState();

  const username = selectUsername(state);

  console.log("Username:", username);

  return username;
};
```

See the other [Store Methods](https://redux.js.org/api/store#store-methods) for subscribing to state changes and dispatching actions to your store from outside React.